# Access property in ListView that is not coming from ItemsSource

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

My `ListView` is bound to `MyTexts` list. Nevertheless i need to bind `TextCell's Text` to property that is not comming from `Texts` (`StandAloneProperty`). How can i do that?

```
<ListView
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedText, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyTexts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell
                        Text="{Binding StandAloneProperty, StringFormat='Value: {0}'}"
                        TextColor="{Binding Color}"
                    />                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: where is `StandAloneProperty` defined?  Is it on the same base VM as `MyTexts` or somewhere else?  Have you read up on [Relative Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings)?

Comment: @Jason it's located in same VM

Comment: see the "Bind to an ancestor" example in the above linked doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your binding `Source` to the current page, and access to `StandAloneProperty`, from BindingContext which is your ViewModel.

```
<ContentPage x:Name="pageRef"
...

<ListView
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedText, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyTexts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell
                        Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference pageRef} Path=BindingContext.StandAloneProperty, StringFormat='Value: {0}'}"
                        TextColor="{Binding Color}"
                    />                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```